# Is there a limit to how many SKUs you can request details for with the Google Play IABv3 api?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I'm working on making an in app billing implementation for my companies app, using [IABv3](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_reference.html) I noticed that I was getting error code 5: Developer Error when requesting details on our whole list of products, but not if I requested just those in a specific category. I theorized that it's a length issue, and put a test loop in there that removed one of the sku's from my list and tried again until it completed successfully. This happened when I got down to 20 skus in my list. Does anyone know if it is indeed a length issue and can point me to where it's documented? I'd like to put a check in to make sure that it will always go through even if our customers have purchased all of our products. For now I set it so that if it's more than 20 it requests in two parts, but I'd like to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there seems to be:
https://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=136

Unfortunately this is not documented by Google and I panicked when I faced it!

Comment: Me too! It took me a while to figure it out. Was glad it happened when I was in development not in the field.